# Docker run container on different port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am new to docker. Just tried to run a container on port 80

```
docker run -p 80:80 kitematic/hello-world-nginx
```

and it seems to be working fine. I can get to the site at http://192.168.99.100/

but i tried changing the port to

```
docker run -p 70:50 kitematic/hello-world-nginx
```

and i cannot get to site at  http://192.168.99.100:70. So how can i set a different port and connect to site  please?

Comment: isn't that should be 70:80?

Comment: Shouldn't you do `docker run -p 70:80 kitematic/hello-world-nginx` ? Nginx is probably listening on 80 port inside docker container.

Answer (score 12):

Please try:

```
docker run -p 70:80 kitematic/hello-world-nginx
```

binding port is probably mistyped in the command you provided.

Comment: yes, it is a mistyping. Apologies, working fine now.